# Why defining move constructor deletes move assignment operator

Tags: c++

When i write `"f5() = X(33);"`(when move constructor in comment line) the compiler does not throw errors.
But when I add a Move Constructor compiler says:

```
" 'X &X::operator =(const X &)': attempting to reference a deleted function "
```

is move constructor delete assignment operator ??

```
#include <iostream>

class X {
    int* p;
public:
    X(int ii = 0) { p = new int(ii); };
    X(const X& obj) { this->p = new int(*(obj.p)); };
//  X(X&& obj) { this->p = new int(*(obj.p)); delete obj.p; obj.p=nullptr;
};



X f5() {
    return X(5);
}

int main() {

    f5() = X(33);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: put the full error, and message, it will be clearer:
`message :  'X &X::operator =(const X &)': function was implicitly deleted because 'X' has a user-defined move constructor`

Comment: Unrelated: your move constructor should look like this instead: `X(X&& obj) { this->p = obj.p; obj.p = nullptr; }` And you need a destructor to `delete p;`. Also, since your class has a pointer member, the class needs explict copy/move assignment operators that copy/move the *value* the pointer is pointing at rather than copy/move the pointer *itself*, per the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). The default generated assignment operators will not suffice in this example.

Answer (score 4):

```
f5() = X(33);
```

would be calling the assignment operator, because an X object already exists there. It's an assignment, not a construction. Before you had a move constructor, it was calling an auto-generated assignment operator.

Now, the compiler is unwilling (well, forbidden) to generate a default assignment operator because you implement a move constructor. The logic goes, you probably know better about your type, so it will let you implement

```
X &X::operator =(const X &)
```

Comment: To complement the answer, this conference talk slides https://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf fully cover what is default generated or deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The error message (`'X &X::operator =(const X &)': function was implicitly deleted because 'X' has a user-defined move constructor`) clearly answers "yes" to your question. But you apparently want to know the motivation for this rule in C++.

The rule was introduced in C++11 (together with move semantics) to enforce the "Rule of 3/5", which says that all of the following must be used together or not at all:

- copy constructor
- copy assignment operator
- move constructor
- move assignment operator
- destructor

(in some situations, it is ok to omit move or copy aiir of constructor/assignment).

Similarly, it would make sense to delete the copy assignment operator when a copy constructor is defined, but it could not be done in 2011 to preserve backward compatibility.

Your code is a good illustration of why the Rule of 3/5 is needed. As is, your class leaks memory. If you add a destructor with `delete p`, but don't define a move assignment operator, then with your example you get a double deletion (undefined behavior, likely crash).

Finally, note that your move constructor is wrong.

Comment: suggest edit, adding at the end "`delete this->p;` should be done before `this->p = new int(*(obj.p));`"

Comment: haha. right. indeed, you are correct. I stopped thinking after noticing the silly order. We could still edit in a correct alternative.